# otherButtonTitles in UIAlertView

Tags: objective-c, uialertview

I was just curious about how can i attach some different task to the otherButtonTitle of UIAlertView.
The cancel button automatically take you out of the application but if i want to attach a different task with the otherButtonTitle ,what should i do?

Thanks,

Answer (score 22, accepted):

UIAlertView delegate "didDismissWithButtonIndex" get called every time u click any button.

Try this:

```
UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" 
                                                message:messageString
                                               delegate:self 
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Back"
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"Reply",@"Delete",nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{
  if (buttonIndex == 1)
  {
    NSLog(@"Reply");
    UIAlertView *myalert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button Clicked" message:@"U clicked Reply " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [myalert show];
    [myalert release];  
  }

  if (buttonIndex == 2)
  {
    NSLog(@"Delete");
    UIAlertView *myalert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button Clicked" message:@"U clicked Delete " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [myalert show];
    [myalert release];  
  }
}
```

Comment: Its not dong anything when i click any of those buttons.

Comment: Correct answer. Tip: Do not confuse `didDismissWithButtonIndex` (invoked *after* the UIAlertView leaves the screen hierarchy) with `clickedButtonAtIndex` (invoked while the UIAlertView is still on-screen and still part of, and dramatically affecting, the screen view hierarchy). I found this mix-up in other StackOverflow answers and other places on the web.